# Refresh recyclerViewAdapter after an insertion in room

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

In `onCreateView` of my `Fragment` I try get data from DB. I use Android room.

if I get `null` or 0 rows - I show button "Update". User pres this button and get data from server, and insert to DB. After that I want refresh `RecyclerView` and load data from DB again.

I try load data in `onCreateView`:

```
MyApplication.me().getDatabase().categoryDao().getAll()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(categories -> {
                    if (categories == null || categories.isEmpty()) {
                        price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categories);
                        categoryAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickHandler());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
                    }
                });
```

If DB has data - all fine. If data not found I show Button and after press make rest request and get result in this code

```
@Override
        public void onNext(ProductsResponse value) {
            ProductService.me().saveProducts(value.getProductItems());
        }
```

Method saveProducts Save data in DB and after yhat I need refresh adapter !!!BUT!!!

```
public void saveProducts(List<ProductItem> products) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (ProductItem item : products) {
                ............
                productList.add(product);
            }
            MyApplication.me().getDatabase().productDao().insertAll(productList);
        }).start();

    }
```

this method in new Thread. I tried this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM categories")
    Flowable<List<Category>> getAll();
```

and after each insert triggered  this code

```
.subscribe(categories -> {
                        if (categories == null || categories.isEmpty()) {
                            price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categories);
                            categoryAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickHandler());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
                        }
                    });
```

But adapter not refresh

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your RecyclerView visible again:

```
.subscribe(categories -> {
                    if (categories == null || categories.isEmpty()) {
                        price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        price.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // HIDE BUTTON
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //SHOW LIST
                        CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(categories);
                        categoryAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickHandler());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
                    }
                });
```